# Python: Is isinstance() necessary in this case?

Tags: python, overloading

I defined a class `Time` that has three int attributes: `hrs, min, sec`

And I defined methods `intToTime()` that convert a `Time` instance to an `int`, which is the number of seconds in that time, and also a method `timeToInt()` that do the reverse.

I'd like them to implement `__add__`, so I can do things like **"TimeA + TimeB" or "TimeA + 100"**, where 100 is the number of seconds add to TimeA.

As I'd like to merge these two (since there's no overloading in Python),

```
def __add__(self,num):
    return Time.intToTime(self,Time.timeToInt(self)+num)

def __add__(self,other):
    return Time.intToTime(self,Time.timeToInt(self)+Time.timeToInt(other))
```

"num" is supposed to be an int, "other" is another Time instance. I know one way using isinstance().

But my question is,
in this case, how should I implement such an **add** without using isinstance()?

Comment: But you are not using isintance right now.

Comment: The latter `__add__` shadows the former one, since there's no method overloading in python.

Comment: Here, a Time instance is just a combination of three ints: hrs, min and sec

Comment: If I was in your position, I'd drop the addition with ints meaning addition of seconds and, if necessary, add a convenience constructor that needs only the seconds (not hours, not minutes). `t + Time.seconds(5)` is much easier to understand than `t + 5` -- plus 5 *what*?

Comment: Personally, I don't think you _should_ be able to add `int`s to `Time`s. In your example of `timeA + 100`, it's not clear from the structure of the code what the 100 should represent (Hours? Nanoseconds? Millenia?). You should require clients to be explicit: `timeA + Time(seconds=100)`

Comment: @delnan you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 7):

You really have two choices: EAFP or LYBL. EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission) means use try/except:

```
def __add__(self, other):
   try:
       return Time.intToTime(self, Time.timeToInt(self)+Time.timeToInt(other))
   except AttributeError as e:
       return Time.intToTime(self, Time.timeToInt(self) + other)
```

Note that `Time.timeToInst(self)` is kind of weird; you would normally write that `self.timeToInt()`.

LYBL means look before you leap - i.e. isinstance. You already know that one.

Comment: That is IMHO too big. What if the `AttributeError` happens elsewhere? I'd do `try: add = Time.timeToInt(other) \n except AttributeError as e: add = other` and then use `add` to add it: `return Time.intToTime(self, Time.timeToInt(self) + add)`

Answer (score 1):

You'd better make `intToTime` and `timeToInt` module level functions, the same level as your class `Time`, and implement your `__add__` like this:

```
def __add__(self, num):
    if isinstance(num, Time):
        num=timeToInt(num)
    elif not isinstance(num, int):
        raise TypeError, 'num should be an integer or Time instance'
    return intToTime(timeToInt(self)+num)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use overloads in python but it requires extra code to handle it for you. You can find what you are looking for in a package called [pythonlangutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonlangutil/0.1) which is available on pypi.

```
from pythonlangutil.overload import Overload,signature

@Overload
@signature("int")
def __add__(self,num):
    return Time.intToTime(self,Time.timeToInt(self)+num)

@__add__.overload
@signature("Time")
def __add__(self,other):
    return Time.intToTime(self,Time.timeToInt(self)+Time.timeToInt(other))
```